# PHPMailer - Mail not accepted from server Error

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I searched web for this issue but none of them solve my problem. I am trying to send single mail using PHPMailer. But I am getting this error in my browser screen.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 
The following From address failed: mymailid@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,,
SMTP server error:

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: mymailid@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server
```

My code to send mail is.

```
<?php 
    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail -> SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail -> IsSMTP();
    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail -> Port = 587;
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail -> Username = 'mymailid@gmail.com';
    $mail -> Password = '*********';

    $mail -> setFrom("mymailid@gmail.com","Name");
    $mail -> addReplyTo("mymailid@gmail.com","Name");
    $mail -> Subject = $subject;
    $mail -> msgHTML($msg);
    $mail -> addAddress($to);

    if(!$mail -> send()) {
        echo "<h3>Mailer Error: ". $mail-> ErrorInfo . "</h3>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    }

?>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manoj Kumar, replace these and then try, 
    1] replace `$mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';` with ` $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl' `;
  2]  replace ` $mail -> Port = 587; ` with ` $mail -> Port = 465; `  ( both are OK but if get error use this one )

Comment: No, don't do that. You should not use ssl - it's been deprecated since 1998, and will have no effect on your problem, and this error is coming after a secure connection has been established. It would help if you posted the complete SMTP transcript - show us what led up to the error, not just what happened afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am also Enabled "allow less secure apps access" option in my Gmail account. Still Error is same.

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: No. I didn't got solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail didn't accept your email and password as correct. You should use real credentials to authentificate or they will block it

Comment: I am using my real Gmail account password.

Comment: Try using it without setFrom then

Comment: @InyaProduction, use of setFrom is OK, no any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am also Enabled "allow less secure apps access" option in my Gmail account. Still Error is same.